# Yeoman/Grunt Angular install - sass sourcemap issue

Tags: angularjs, sass, gruntjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have the correct versions of Compass and Sass installed on my machine and have had no issues creating sourcemaps with other projects, i.e my base set-up works.

My problem is very specific: it's with the 'yo-angular' grunt install.

I have amended the Gruntfile.js as follows (by adding the sourcemap: true flag) :

```
// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
compass: {
options: {
    sourcemap: true,
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
```

And i have changed the debug flag to false:

```
},
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: false
    }
  }
},
```

This works fine, throws no errors in 'grunt serve', and on inspecting the generated main.css file the references generated by the sourcemap main.css are entirely accurate.

But, oddly, the elements panel of Chrome Dev Tools refers to completely different line numbers.

The way that yo angular process builds is presumably the issue, and I notice that the files/folder structure (e.g. the _sass files are all empty) that the host is looking at are different to my dev files so maybe it's just impossible to map to them?

Quick PS: I know that many have struggled to get sass sourcemaps working at all, because of issues with Compass and so on, but just to reiterate I am not asking for help in getting a basic set-up established - I have managed that. The specific problem that I have is making the 'yo angular' stack to work with sourcemaps. I imagine that others have had the same problem. I have searched all over this and other sites to no avail and posted issues on github without a result.

Please Help and thanks in anticipation!